# I/O operation on closed file in python.requests

Tags: python

I have a pretty simple code:

```
from rauth import OAuth1Session, OAuth1Service
import requests, urllib

#preparing...
#...

#request
session.request(request_type, url, header_auth, headers = headers, files = {'file' : open('./my_file.pdf', 'rb')}, **req_kwargs)
```

The error is `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

What's up with this?

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rauth/session.py", line 210, in request
    return super(OAuth1Session, self).request(method, url, **req_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 422, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 360, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 297, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 432, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 147, in _encode_files
    rf = RequestField(name=k, data=fp.read(),
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`
```

Comment: Please do include the **full** traceback of your exception.

Comment: Can you try just a simple session: session = requests.Session() and then you session.request()

Answer (score 1):

The `OAuth1Session` object will first establish a token (it may need to get a fresh token); this probably causes the file to be read and posted before the real request is posted.

You may need to first do a *different* request without a file upload to establish the token, *then* upload the file.

Alternatively read the whole file into memory first instead of handing in a file object:

```
session.request(request_type, url, header_auth, headers=headers,
                files={'file': open('./my_file.pdf', 'rb').read()},
                **req_kwargs)
```